# В Google Chrome не срабатывает scrollIntoView по событию 'wheel'

Tags: javascript, html, google-chrome, wheelevent

Пытаюсь настроить прокрутку к нужной секции документа по событию wheel.
В Firefox все работает корректно, а в Google Chrome прокрутка не происходит, хотя само событие срабатывает. При этом по клику scrollIntoView работает, в т.ч. на GoogleChrome
[Пример на кодепен](https://codepen.io/jyruqnra/pen/VwKzzeE)

```
    <div class='div1'></div>
    <div class='div2'></div>
    <div class='div3'></div>
```

```
    div {
      width: 100%;
      height: 400px;
      border: 1px solid;
    }
    
    .div1 {
      background: gray; 
    }
    .div2 {
      background: gray; 
    }
    .div3 {
      background: green; 
    }
```

```
    var div3 = document.querySelector('.div3');
    
    document.documentElement.addEventListener('wheel', function(evt) {
      console.log('wheel');
      div3.scrollIntoView({behavior: 'smooth'});
      document.addEventListener('scroll', function() {
        console.log(pageYOffset);
      })
    });
    document.documentElement.addEventListener('click', function() {
      div3.scrollIntoView({behavior: 'smooth'});
    });
```

Comment: Добавлять события внутри событий не стоит будет расход памяти (каждая подписка должна в по хорошему сопровождаться отпиской если отслеживание времненное, и вообще). Не могу сказать что прокрутка не работает в хроме, она работает, но не совсем так. Из вопроса не понятно где именно колесико при прокрутке должно вызывать прокрутку страницы. Есть ли более четкие условия, например: "над первым  дивом"? Потому что если не конкретизировать то будут баги в том числе не возможность прокрутить страницу вверх.

Comment: В данном примере добавила eventListener на scroll только чтобы отследить, происходит ли скролл страницы. В рабочем проекте вложенное событие не использую. Отписка от событий в рабочем проекте также имеется, здесь не добавляла для простоты примера. В даннном примере предполагается, что событие wheel должно срабатывать в любом месте документа и вызывать scrollIntoView. Повторюсь, пример здесь очень упрощенный, но суть проблемы отражает

Comment: Если вы прокрутите в вашем коде колесико вверх то скрол пройзойдет, это то что я успел заметить

Comment: Еще один странный момент: если в GoogleChrome поставить точку останова внутри eventListener-а события wheel до либо на точке div3.scrollIntoView({behavior: 'smooth'}); , то после остановки и запуска выполнения кода, прокрутка происходит как надо

Comment: @DaniilLoban Да, тоже это заметила, но не нашла объяснение, почему не работает при скролле вниз

Comment: Объяснение описанного @DaniilLoban поведения может быть такое: браузурное событие scroll блокирует выполнение scrollIntoView. А в случае, если в начале документа прокрутить колесико вверх, то скролл по умолчанию не происходит (т.к. выше некуда прокручивать), и событие scrollIntoView не блокируется